# Making my search box a bit more mobile friendly

Tags: css, elasticsearch, mobile

Right now it looks great on desktop but for mobile it just kind of floats in the middle of the page and when you try to type in it you can't see what you're typing.

[The image you see here is for desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ6pe.png)

[On mobile it's just a little blob in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL7uC.png)

Desktop it's up on the top right hand side for reference. Why would it move to the middle on mobile?

```
    // Search
.block-search {
    display: inline-block;
    .label {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    input {
        border-radius: 50px;
        height: 40px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 44px;
    }
    .control {
        border-top: 0;
        clear:none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .action.search {
        background: #5a5a5a;
        border-radius: 50px;
        height: 34px;
        right: 4px;
        top: 3px;
        width: 34px;
    }
    .search-autocomplete ul:not(:empty) {
        border-color: #c2c2c2;
        border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    }
    .search-autocomplete ul {
        li {
            border-color: #c2c2c2;
            &:hover {
                background-color: #e5e5e5;
            }
            .amount {
                color: #444;
            }
        }
        .selected {
            background-color: #e5e5e5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't possibly know without seeing your code.

Comment: Yeah the code would be good.
Maybe you can solve it by using min-width and min-height

Comment: Sorry about that.. let me post some code. @tomitheninja

Comment: @ObsidianAge code has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019, it's neither fashionable nor practical to use `float`s for layout. Instead, you should use `flexbox` or (if your design requires more complex layout) `CSS Grid`. You want to keep your layout as "high" up as possible. Set the rules in the parent container(s) and let the children flow however you've determined.

Here's a simple example.

- Set a parent container width that can be no larger than the width of the viewport
- Center all `header` content
- Try not to set explicit `height` on elements. Instead, use padding. This will scale nicely at different user-adjusted font sizes.

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

.container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 100vw;
}

header {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.searchBox {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <input type="search" class="searchBox" placeholder="Search…">  
  </header>  
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m9n3xyc4/3/)